# Group CPT posts by custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop

Being honest I've stucked with my code. So I have two things:
- CPT called: opencourses
- custom taxonomy called: typ

currently I have a template which displays pure list of CPT posts. And it works. But i want to enhance that by grouping them by custom taxonomy (which is available only to this CPT).

This is the code:

```
<?php if (have_rows('lista_szkolen')) : while (have_rows('lista_szkolen')) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php $szkolenie = get_sub_field('szkolenie'); ?>
        <?php if ($szkolenie) :
                    $post = $szkolenie;
                    setup_postdata($post);
                    $grupa = get_field('oznaczenie_szkolenia');
                    ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="coursWrapper">
                        <div class="visibleInfoCourses" style="border-left: 5px solid <?php echo $grupa['value']; ?> ">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>
                                    <?php if (get_field('nowosc')) : ?><span class="labelItem labeImNew">Nowość</span><?php endif ?>
                                    <?php if (get_field('new_form')) : ?><span class="labelItem labeImNewForm">Nowa formuła</span><?php endif ?>
                                    <?php if (get_field('new_date_info')) : ?><span class="labelItem labeImNewDate">Zmiana terminu</span><?php endif ?>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <div class="buttonsHereRight">
                                        <button class="btnBorderGrey btn-lean-sm">Terminy warsztatów</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="InvisibleInfoCourses" style="border-left: 5px solid <?php echo $grupa['value']; ?> ">
                            <?php if (have_rows('terminy_warsztatow')) : $i = 0; ?>
                                <div class="TerminySzkolen" style="padding: 0;">
                                    <?php while (have_rows('terminy_warsztatow')) : the_row();
                                        $i++;
                                        $hotele = get_sub_field('polecane_hotele');
                                        $zapisy = get_sub_field('stan_zapisow'); ?>
                                        <div class="InvisibleInfoCoursesDetails" <?php if ($zapisy == 'Sprzedane') : echo " style='opacity:.6;'";endif; ?>>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                    <span><img src="<?php the_sub_field('logotyp') ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('lokalizacja') ?>"></span>
                                                    <span><i style="opacity: .6;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i><?php the_sub_field('data') ?></span>
                                                    <span><i style="opacity: .6;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i><?php the_sub_field('lokalizacja') ?></span>
                                                    <span><i style="opacity: .6;" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i><?php echo $zapisy; ?></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                    <div class="buttonsHereRight">
                                                        <!-- <a class="btn-lean btn-lean-sm" target="_blank" download="Formularz zgłoszeniowy" href="<?php the_sub_field('przycisk') ?>" onclick="gtag('event', 'szkolenia', {'event_category' : 'szkolenie-otwarte-lista-szkoleń','event_label' : '<?php the_title() ?> '});" <?php if ($zapisy == 'Sprzedane') : echo " style='display:none'";endif; ?>>Zapisz się</a> -->
                                                        <!-- <a class="btn-lean btn-lean-sm" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" onclick="gtag('event', 'szkolenia', {'event_category' : 'szkolenie-otwarte-lista-szkoleń','event_label' : '<?php the_title() ?> '});" <?php if ($zapisy == 'Sprzedane') : echo " style='display:none'"; endif; ?>>Zapisz się</a> -->
                                                        <a class="btn-lean btn-lean-sm" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" <?php if ($zapisy == 'Sprzedane') : echo " style='display:none'"; endif; ?>>Zapisz się</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php endif ?>
<?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: But your not doing any query in there - you get all your posts from ACF field, so how would you like it to work? It means that ACF should magically group posts by your criteria... You’ll have to rewrite all that code and change the ACF field to make it work...